# How to save the input in a list on python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I code this into my python 3 and everytime that im going to run it. Of course it performs it function but not the things i wanted it to run. It will ask you to put some course that your want to add into the list which is the "courses_list" but my problem was everytime i type another input (courses) it just only replace whats inside the courses_list. It didn't save it like what i want.

```
def courses():
  courses_list = []
  coursesInput = input("Insert the course you want")
  courses_list.insert(0, coursesInput)
  print (courses_list)
  courses()

courses()
```

Result : Example i type (CompScie and Physics)

```
CompSci
['CompScie']
Physics
['Physics']
```

so how can i save the result of the courses_list so everytime that it ask me again to give another courses it will insert it to the courses_list.

What i want to happen :

```
CompScie 
['CompScie']
Physics
['Physics', 'CompScie']
```

Comment: If you don't want to create a new list each time the function is called, why do you create a new list each time the function is called?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have made the list inside the function. So everytime the function gets called, it creates a new list and appends the input. What you need to do is create a list outside the scope of function and modify it using argument.

```
def courses(c_list):
  coursesInput = input("Insert the course you want")
  c_list.insert(0, coursesInput)
  print (c_list)
  courses(c_list)

courses_list = []
courses(course_list)
```